# Is there a way to create a folder that is interpreted by the OS (Windows, OS, Linux) as a single file?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, filesystems

The reason why I need this is because for example: There are a lots of files and folders inside a "some_important_folder" folder. User can usually browse to "some_important_folder" folder and go deeper into it to see its' subfolders and files like in any normal file explorer can do. But since in my use case, the user doesn't need to interact with the files and folders in "some_important_folder" folder at all. Therefore, I was wondering if there is any way to hide the complexity of the folders in "some_important_folder" folder and show to user as a single file only. But my programs (written in C++) can still somehow access the files and folders in it like normal such as: "C:\Users\user\Documents\some_important_folder\someFolder\someFileThatUserDoesntNeedToKnow.exe"
Something like .rar or .zip file but since the "some_important_folder" folder might be very big in size (more than TB), I don't think it would be good to convert the whole folder to a .zip file as it would take lots of redundant space from the hard disc and the process would be very slow

Comment: You can try to look into uncompressed zip files: https://superuser.com/questions/411394/zip-files-without-compression

Comment: Alternatively there is stuff like: https://www.dimin.net/software/pole/ (this was just the first example my google search found, no idead how good it is) I know that, for example, Skyrim uses something similar for their game files.

Comment: if you worry the file is too large to fit in RAM - you can always use a memorymap to only use a portion of the file at a time, im not sure if there's an implementation of a known file extension that does this the way you want it to, but you could always make your own basic file structure

Comment: On linux you can loop mount a squashfs file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered encrypting your folders? That way if you wanted to only access the folder using your C++ app, you could pass down the password/decrypted for it, making your app the only access point you'd have to that folder.

Comment: I am not trying to limit the user's access, I just want to let user know that oh this is a single file, if user want to copy to other PC, he just needs to copy this "file" to that PC. I'm not sure whether encrypting it would confuses the user like, why is it encrypted, why can't I access this folder? I'm not sure maybe this works too haha

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both windows and linux have similar technology.

On windows, you can use "Compound File Binary Format". It is a general-purpose file format that provides a file-system-like structure within a file for the storage of arbitrary, application-specific streams of data. In fact, ealier office doc file format is based on this technology. The following is the doc link from microsoft and wiki. And I believe you can google some sample code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cfb/53989ce4-7b05-4f8d-829b-d08d6148375b
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format

On linux, you can loop mount a file as file system as @stark mentioned. You can google "linux loop mount file", the following is the first article I found:

https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/2096-use-a-file-as-a-linux-block-device